# How to do an operation in two arrays and stock it in one?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a new programmer in C and lately i was eager to learn machine learning. I made a program just to understand how kernels work but it turned out it gives me an undefined behaviour error. Problem is most likely in the calculating O array or might be in printing it.

```
int S[M][N];
srand(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        S[M][N] =rand() % ARRAY_RANGE;
        printf("%d\t", S[M][N]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


//S[M][N] initialized and printed here. No problem.

int K[3][3];

printf("Enter the kernel: \n");

for( i = 0 ; i<3; i++ ){
    for(j = 0; j<3; j++){
        scanf("%d", &K[i][j]);
    }
}

for( i = 0 ; i<3; i++ ){
    for(j = 0; j<3; j++){
        printf("%4d", K[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}

 unsigned long long int O[M][N] = {{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}};
   long int sum,m,n;

for(i = 0; i < M-2 ; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < N-2; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
         for(l = 0; l < 3; l++){
             O[i+1][j+1] += (S[i+l][j+k])*(K[k][l]);           

               }        
          } 
     } 
 }


       for (i=0; i<M; i++){
          for(j=0; j<N; j++){
             printf("%d", O[i][j]);
             }
              printf("\n");
         }
    return 0;
}
```

It should look like:

```
0        0         0          0         0
0   *calculated 3 integers of O array*  0
0   *calculated 3 integers of O array*  0 
0   *calculated 3 integers of O array*  0
0       0          0          0         0
```

but instead it gives random really big or really small numbers like"3241242" or "-2431452" where i wrote *calculated 3 integers of O array*.

-Edited how i initialized S array. I've included stdio.h, stdlib.h, time.h too.

Comment: Please explain what it should do, what does it do instead, what is the exact error, is it a compile time error or runtime error etc. We need specifics to be able to help you

Comment: Sorry i am new to Stack Overflow and can't reply immediately: It should lok like a matrix 5x5 that is 5 zeros on top, 5 zeros on bottom and middle ones are like:                 
                 0  *calculated three integers of O array*    0

Comment: And instead it does what?

Comment: @whysoserious No problem and welcome to SO! I recommend [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59332561/edit) to provide the input/output as concrete examples, with explanation. Better to hardcode in some data than rely on `scanf`, which could be anything. Thanks.

Comment: i don't know the type of error but it looks like an integer overflow. Where i wrote *calculated three integers of O array* there is random really big numbers or really small negative ones like: 19725214 or -24246214

Comment: Edited what should've seemed.

Comment: Your code is fine **if** you initialize S. Show us the code you're using to initialize S please.

Comment: Edited how i initialized it.

Comment: `S[i][j] = rand() % ARRAY_RANGE;`?? (not `S[M][N]` - which would set out of bounds every iteration) Same error with `printf("%d\t", S[i][j]);` You also have omitted the necessary modifier `"ll"` in `printf ("%lld", O[i][j]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of small problems (some typo, some not). To begin, the typo related errors are:

```
    S[M][N] =rand() % ARRAY_RANGE;
    printf("%d\t", S[M][N]);
```

Which obviously should be:

```
    S[i][j] = rand() % ARRAY_RANGE;
    printf("%d\t", S[i][j]);
```

You have a *conversion specifier* mismatch which invokes *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to print `O` (type `unsigned long long int`) as `"%d"` (signed `int`). A proper conversion specifier for `long long unsigned` would be `"%llu"`.

There is no need to specify zero for every element in `O`, simply initialize the first element and then all other elements are set zero by default, e.g.

```
    unsigned long long int O[M][N] = {{0}};
```

See [C11 Standard - § 6.7.9 Initialization (p21)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

Putting it altogether and adding the headers and defines, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define M 5
#define N M
#define ARRAY_RANGE 1000

int main (void) {

    int S[M][N];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            S[i][j] = rand() % ARRAY_RANGE;
            printf("%d\t", S[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    int K[3][3];

    printf("Enter the kernel: \n");

    for (int i = 0 ; i<3; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &K[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i<3; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%4d", K[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }

    unsigned long long int O[M][N] = {{0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < M-2 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N-2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++){
                    O[i+1][j+1] += (S[i+l][j+k])*(K[k][l]);           
                }        
            } 
        } 
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf (" %5llu", O[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the unused variables `long int sum,m,n;` were omitted)

**Example 3x3 Entered**

```
$ cat dat/3x3.txt
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/three2d <dat/3x3.txt
445     971     809     962     208

648     547     459     981     634

656     529     534     710     10

796     548     696     998     647

215     857     384     698     54

Enter the kernel:
   1   2   3


   4   5   6


   7   8   9


     0     0     0     0     0
     0 27643 33359 22960     0
     0 26218 33460 27418     0
     0 25653 31352 20828     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. One more thing:How you get kernel with scanf at 3x3 format? When i want to get it it is always 9x1 format because i have to hit enter when i read something with scanf.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &K[i][j]);` will read 9 numbers in any format. The `"%d"` format specifier ignores all whitespace, so I could have used 9 values on the first line and it would read fine. Also note I ***redirect*** the file on `stdin` to the program calling the program as `./bin/three2d <dat/3x3.txt`. I'm not "entering" individual values and pressing `[Enter]` in between.